# Speed up pd.read_excel in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm writing python that read excel data and import it to database. For 10,000~30,000 records is fine. But 150,000+ records it took me over 13 seconds. How i can speed up it ?

```
f = request.files['file']

all_data = {} #insert group data

df = pd.read_excel (f)
df = df.dropna(how='all')
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
df.index.name = excel_conf['config']['default_config']['identification_column']['name'] #column header identification
df.index += 1 #raise index to a valid one
df = df.fillna("")

########## loop take times #########
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row_dict = []
    for key in excel_conf['config']['column_config']: #column header name lists
        row_dict.append({
            key : row[key]
            #key (from excel config) row[key] (row value from excel)
        })
    index_key = index_keygen(create_blake2s_signature(...)) #just create index key stuffs, i shorted it
    # add child data to main
    all_data[index_key] = row_dict
    #"test_key" : { "key":"value",... }
 ####################################

insert_db(all_data) #this is fast
```

Comment: You can expect the code to be extremely slow as soon as you involve things like `iterrows` or `itertuples`. What are you trying to achieve in that loop?

Comment: @pavel : i'm extracting data row by row from df (pd.read_excel) to create a new json format to put it in API . is this concept correct ?

Comment: Not correct given that pandas has a dedicated `DataFrame.to_json()` method.

Comment: @pavel i've done benchmark between DataFrame.to_json()  and df.iterrows() . it seem to_json() slower than df.iterrows() around 20%

Comment: You might want to share how exactly you used `to_json` because it shouldn't be the case.